# Sorting a vector of pointers using std::sort resulting in jumbled addresses?

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, vector

I'm writing a function to sort a vector of class pointers. Before sorting, the vector contains the following pointers:

```
{0x784170, 0x7841a0, 0x784050, 0x783f10, 0x783f40, 0x7832a0, 0x7832d0, 0x7831a0, 0x7831d0, 0x783080, 0x7830b0, 0x782f40, 0x782f70, 0x7827c0, 0x7827f0}
```

After sorting, it contains these:

```
{0x3141954a38, 0x3141954a38, 0x784050, 0x783f10, 0x783f40, 0x7832a0, 0x7832d0, 0x7831a0, 0x7831d0, 0x783080, 0x7830b0, 0x782f40, 0x782f70, 0x7827c0, 0x80}
```

The following is my code:

```
bool DNodeComparator(DNode* x, DNode* y)
{
return x->getDFN() < y->getDFN();
}

void sortFunction(){
    vector<DNode*> operations = ApplicationGraph.getOperations();
    std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), mycomparator);
}

class DGraph
{
    private:
        vector<DNode*> Nodes;

    public:
        vector<DNode*> getOperations(){return Nodes;}
};
```

The code runs on a dependency graph which contains a vector of DNode* objects. I'm returning this vector of pointers and sorting each node by it's DFN field. The DNode class contains Operation* objects, some boolean flags, and an int value for computing the depth first numbering of the dependency graph. The addresses shown in the first line are a result of a gdb `print operations` call right before the `std::sort` call. The addresses in the second line are a `print operations` call right after `std::sort`.

I've tried a couple more debugging steps, but still can't reconcile this error. Returning the vector of DNode* creates a desired copy of this vector which is stored in a separate address, so that modifying this new vector (such as by adding more DNodes) does not modify the actual vector in the graph class. This shouldn't cause any problems as the vector still contains each DNode*.

Comment: Paste exact not in place of `{some pointers}`;

Comment: I think there is a problem in your code, but not the code you have shown us here.

Comment: I suspect that some of `{some pointers}` actually point to (local) objects that have been destroyed so their storage is being reused.

Comment: or multithreading is used, but sortFunction is not protected by some synchronization object

Comment: `std::sort` cannot change the values in the range, it can only re-order them, so the problem is in something you are not showing us.

Comment: All of the pointers are created previously using the `new` keyword and then immediately added to the `ApplicationGraph`. In my understanding, no object created by `new` can be destroyed and its memory reallocated without explicitly calling `delete`. Is this false?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example based on your comparator.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Obj {
  int id;
  int getID() {
    return id; }
  Obj(int i) : id(i) {} };

bool mycomparator(Obj* a, Obj* b) {
  return a->getID() < b->getID(); }

int main(int, char* []) {
  std::vector<Obj*> myvector;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    myvector.push_back(new Obj(i)); }

  std::random_shuffle(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());

  for (std::vector<Obj*>::iterator i = myvector.begin();
       i < myvector.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << (*i) << " " << (*i)->getID() << " "; }

  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), mycomparator);

  for (std::vector<Obj*>::iterator i = myvector.begin();
       i < myvector.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << (*i) << " " << (*i)->getID() << " "; }

  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0; }
```

Ouput

```
0x80010308 2 0x80010318 1 0x80010328 3 0x800102f8 0
0x800102f8 0 0x80010318 1 0x80010308 2 0x80010328 3
```

How is your code different from this?